# Find a point that is at a distance from another and both belong to same line.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say I've got this line in $\mathbb R^2$:

$$
\ell: y = \frac{2}{3}x + \frac{11}{3}
$$

I know a point

$$ A = (2,5) $$

I'd like to find a second point that is at $d$ distance from $A$ and also belongs to $\ell$.

I was thinking about finding a parallel line to $l$ at $d$ distance and find the intersecting point, also using a circle centered on $A$ with a $d$ radius and find the intersecting point, but has to be an easier way.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean $3.667$ or was it really $\dfrac{11}{3}$?

Comment: Is finding the intersection of a circle with this line really that hard? Substitute for $y$ in the equation of the circle and you have a simple quadratic equation in $x$ to solve.

Comment: @stevengregory i'll change it to $11/3$, more elegant.

Comment: In other words, the distance from the point $\left(x, \dfrac 23x + \dfrac{11}{3} \right)$ to the point $(2,5)$ is $d$ and you need to find the value of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intersecting a circle centered on $A$ with $\mathscr l$ is the right idea. You get a system of two equations: $$(x-2)^2+(y-5)^2=d^2 \\ y=\frac23x+\frac{11}3.$$ (The first equation is just the distance formula, squared.) Substitute for $y$ in the first equation to get a straightforward quadratic in $x$, solve that and substitute into the equation of $\mathscr l$ to find the corresponding $y$-coordinates.

However, since $A$ lies on $\mathscr l$ you can compute these points directly: you just have to move a distance of $d$ from $A$ along $\mathscr l$ in either direction. From its equation, we know that the slope of the line is $\frac23$, so a vector that parallels the line is $(3,2)$. Normalize this to get a unit direction vector $\mathbf u$ for the line, and the points you seek are then $A\pm d\mathbf u$.

Comment: Thank you for eloquently conveying this concept. As a tutor I need to become more precise explaining my approaches! +1

Comment: @amd thanks for your time. I'll go with the vector technique as it's easier to program and I bet computationally cheaper.

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla Remember that it only works when the point is on the line. When it’s not, though, you can do something similar using the Pythagorean theorem and point-line distance formula.

Comment: @amd yes indeed. I needed a solution for both points in the same line. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

***Hint***: Let's say we have $x=1$, then $y=4\,\frac{1}{3}$ so $(1,4\,\frac{1}{3}$) is part of your line. Then you just use the distance formula $d=\sqrt{(x_{1}-x_{0})^{2}+(y_{1}-y_{0})^{2}}$ where $(x_{1},y_{1})$ is your point on the line and $(x_{0},y_{0})$ corresponds to your $a$. I hope this helps answer your question.

Comment: Thanks John! $a$ belongs to $l$ as well and the distance $d$ is known. If I put all this in the distance equation I still have two unknowns and only one equation.

Comment: This is precisely “using a circle centered on $A$ with a $d$ radius” mentioned by the OP.

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla You have two equations—this and the equation of the line.

Comment: @amd I'm not so sure about that, OP seemed to suggest finding a line parallel and then finding the intersection. I feel the method I suggested is the simplest one you learn one of the first lessons in vector calc (review).

Comment: I read those as two separate methods, but what you say has merit.